# Не получается простая задача на e-olimp (не проходит проверку)

Tags: c#, проверка

Я не понимаю, почему на e-olimp не засчитывается простейшая задача (там так написано). Только-только начал писать. Язык - C#. [Условие](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/1)

Код ниже:

```
using System;
   public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {     
            int x, i, y;
            string str;
             str = Console.ReadLine(); //Задается число
            i = Convert.ToInt32(str);
             x = i / 10;
             y = i % 10;
            Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y);
        }
    }
```

Также есть офф решение в разделе помощь. Но я не понимаю, в чем проблема

```
using System; 
public class Sum 
{
  private static void Main() 
{
   int ab = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      int b  = ab %10;
      int a  = ab/10;
      Console.WriteLine(a+" "+b);}}
```

Comment: Какой-то сомнительный сервис Вы выбрали. Тут и там ошибки, код тоже неаккуратный.

Comment: Можете что-нибудь посоветовать другое? Интересует C#

Comment: К сожалению, не могу ничего посоветовать, потому что самой на подобные онлайн-обучалки терпения не хватает :)

Comment: А что могли бы посоветовать для начинающего в программировании студента. 1 курс. С чего бы начать?